# Positive symmetric matrices and positive-definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, quadratic-forms

Is a symmetric real matrix with diagonal entries strictly greater than $1$ and off-diagonal entries positive but strictly less than $1$ necessarily positive-semidefinite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope.  Just playing around with my computer, I found the matrix

[$\frac{11}{10}$ $\frac{1}{100}$ $\frac{99}{100}$]

[$\frac{1}{100}$  $\frac{11}{10}$ $\frac{99}{100}$]

[$\frac{99}{100}$ $\frac{99}{100}$  $\frac{11}{10}$]

with determinant $\frac{-25179}{31250}$.

Is this perhaps a misremembering of the definition of a [diagonally dominant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix)?

Comment: Not quite misremembering as much as failing to find a counterexample and being unable to prove the necessity but still not believing in it's veracity.  Thanks for your example!

Comment: @daegan: no problem.  To construct a counterexample, it of course helps to be aware of the theorem about diagonally dominant matrices, so as to stay away from that case.  I did remember that theorem (luckily for me, I learned about Gershgorin's Theorem in a talk I heard last year) so the above was only the third matrix I tried (or technically the fourth: the third one also worked but the coefficients were a little more complicated: it appears in a previous version of this answer).

Answer (score 3):

If the sum of each row is positive, then no eigenvalue can be non-negative: take any eigenvector, and pick the largest (in magnitude) coordinate. After applying the matrix, even if the signs are all perfectly against us, still $0$ will not be crossed (or reached to).

So the correct formulation is $\geq 1$ on the diagonal, and the off-diagonals *in each row* sum to less than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

By [Gershgorin's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) we can conclude that the absolute sum of all non-diagonal entries in each row must be less than 1.  Then the matrix will have positive eigenvalues for diagonal entries > 1.